# Angular2 don't render ChildComponent selector

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to display data in an HTML table. Because the `<tr>` will be repeated many times and it has some logic I wanted to extract that to it's own (child)component.

But rendering a child component within the `<tbody>` allso renders the component as an HTML attribute. My template looks like:

```
<tbody>
    <custom-row [some-data]="data"></custom-row>
</tbody>
```

But when this is rendered, it will look like:

```
<tbody>
    <custom-row>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </custom-row>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to not render te "custom-row" element in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an Angular issue. The browser doesn't render `<custom-row>` inside `<table>` because this tag is invalid there.

Change the selector of your component to `selector: '[custom-row]'` and use it like

```
<tbody>
    <tr custom-row [some-data]="data"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you Günter!